# Does Neo4j have "In" expression?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

i am learning `Cypher` using .NETClient, I've worked with `TSQL` before there was an expression called `In` :

SQL `IN` is an operator used to pull data matching a list of values. A scenario where this proves useful would be if we wanted to retrieve customer data for two or more customers. We can use the IN operator to specify a list of customer names, and SQL will retrieve rows reflecting every customer in the list.

I was Wondering is there anything equal to this expression in `Cypher`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `IN` exists:

```
MATCH (a)
WHERE a.name IN ['Peter', 'Tobias']
RETURN a
```

See the docs for more details: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/cypher/clauses/where/#_lists

Comment: Oh thank you! its kinda hard to search and find these sometimes :)